# Generic type matching at runtime scala 3

Tags: scala, scala-3, higher-kinded-types

I want to a list function (implemented through generic), they share the same function name but different parameter types. For a given parameter variable, is it possible to pick the "suitable" function from the list to call it?

Also is it possible to match type in a trait in scala 3? Like the code below.

I wonder if it possible to achieve this without reflection, e.g. `TypeTag`.

```
trait Target

trait TargetBuilding extends Target
trait TargetUnit extends Target

trait Do[T <: Target] {
  type targetType = T
  def hit(x: T): Unit
}

val x1 = new Do[TargetBuilding] {
  override def hit(x: TargetBuilding): Unit = println("hit " + x.toString)
}

val x2 = new Do[TargetUnit] {
  override def hit(x: TargetUnit): Unit = println("Eat " + x.toString)
}

val q: Seq[Do[_ >: TargetBuilding & TargetUnit <: Target]] = x1 :: x2 :: Nil
//val q: Seq[Do[_ >: TargetBuilding & TargetUnit <: Target]] = x2 :: x1 :: Nil

val data = new TargetBuilding {
  override def toString: _root_.java.lang.String = "a building"
}

q foreach { x =>
  type tt = x.targetType

  data match {
    case y: tt => x.hit(y)
    case _     =>
  }

}
```

If `Target` is assumed to be `sealed`, is there any difference?

Comment: Generics are erased after compile time. You cannot get type at runtime like that. You can store a TypeTag or ClassTag in Do, but I do recommend using a non reflective way for performance purpose, like adding a test method in Target

Comment: Can `Target` be `sealed`? Or is expected that users create new instances?

Comment: Note that `TypeTag` is not supported anymore on Scala 3 anyway (only `ClassTag` is)

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/type-test.html
`TypeTest` exists in Scala 3 to support such operations; it does require reflection, however.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Assume Target can be sealed

Comment: @worldterminator Does something like this work for you? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/6tFUCuOLSxmUYIVM65CkEA/3

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I see your idea. You put  the type checking into each sub class. I guess that can also work. But `Do` will lose T. `TypeTest` is created to solve this though.

Comment: @worldterminator why do you need `Do` to have a `T` at all? Also note that `TypeTest` is slow and non portable.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I guess you are right, partial function is good enough